# Stuck with the Struts-tiles Web Application

Tags: java, struts, tiles, struts-1

I am stuck with this error **"Attribute property has a runtime value of definitions-config.  property must reference a valid Java identifier"**.

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
<set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
<set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>
```

I am working with struts-tiles 1.3.8 in order to create a web application with Header, Footer, Body & Menu. I don't know weather I am missing some jar files? I have no clue. Please help me folks.

Comment: You need to supply version info for Struts, Tiles, etc. for people to help.

Comment: I am working on Struts 1 & Tiles. Coming to the jars, I am using Struts-tiles 1.3.8, Struts-taglib 1.3.8, Struts-core 1.3.8... Moreover I even used 1.3.10 version of jars But it didn't worked.

Comment: Do you have the `chainConfig` `init-param` defined?

Comment: Yes I defined the init-param for the ActionServlet. I do searched in many sites regarding this. I have no clue about the chainconfig.

Answer (score -1):

We can't say where the exact error is occuring. With this code we can't say specifically. But i have a resource on Tiles .

go through this resource , i hope this may help you.

[Struts with Tiles](http://javabynataraj.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-struts-program-using-tiles.html)